# Storing of Quotation Mark Characters in Database

Tags: php, mysql

I am storing large amounts of text in a database. The problem is that when I try to store quotation marks (`‘ ’ “ ”` not `" '`) they store in the database fine although do not show when I show the text from the database.

Should I convert the quotation marks before putting them into the database or on loading the text from the database and what method of converting them would be best suited?

Comment: Are you storing your data as UTF-8?

Comment: The table is set to latin1_swedish_ci but converted using the utf8_encode(); function when loading the text.

Comment: Typographic quotes aren't part of latin1.

Comment: What charset would you sugest I use then?

Comment: To clarify my comment: latin1 in MySQL is actually cp1252. From the 
manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-we-sets.html):  
MySQL's latin1 is the same as the Windows cp1252. This 
means it is the same as the official ISO 8859-1, except latin1 treats the code points between 0x80 and 0x9f as “undefined,”. 
Typographic quotes fall in this range x91, x92, x93, x94. The problem is 
that the php function that you are using, utf8_encode, expects a string 
in "strict" ISO-8859-1. Probably you can find another way to convert this 
characters, but why bother? just use UTF-8 all the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problems would indeed be solved by using UTF8, but if this does not comply with your front end, then just resort to html entities.

This tool should be useful if you cannot use php\something else to do it automaticly: http://leftlogic.com/projects/entity-lookup

Answer (score 0):

Could you store them as `&ldquo; and &rdquo; or &lsquo; and &rsquo;`?

I am presuming the output is in html?